# Special character (@) in Typescript interface

Tags: typescript

I am using and external API which has the following interface:

```
    export interface IResponse {
        @odata.context: string;
    }
```

This gives me syntax error. I can access the property by using obj["@odata.context"] but that's not really the typescript way. Is there a workaround to name the property? It's an interface and wrapping it to a getter method is not what I am looking for.

Comment: The key contains both `'@'` and `'.'`?

Comment: Yes that's correct. OneDrive API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the key `@odata.context` contains a dot then you will be forced to use the index notation regardless of the at char at the beginning, because even if the key was just `odata.context` then doing this:

```
let context = response.odata.context;
```

Would only work for an interface with this structure:

```
export interface IResponse {
    odata: {
        context: string;
    }
}
```

Because of that I see no other option other than:

```
let context = response["@odata.context"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Realise this is a bit old now, but happened upon it as I had the same problem.
Solved (mostly) by surrounding the interface property in quotes:

```
export interface IResponse {
    "@odata.context": string;
}
```

Then Auto-complete works when using it. You still get it as

```
let context = response["@odata.context"]
```

but at least you get autocomplete and nothing complains. Hope it helps someone.